# Looping through shapefiles in GDAL OSGeo4W

Tags: loops, gdal, shapefile, osgeo

I have a list of shape-files that I want to convert to geoJSON. I am using the GDAL OSGeo4W shell to convert.

Firstly, I define the coordinate system (as they arent defined for the shapefiles) then i convert them.

I can do it for individual files easily, however as I have over 200 shapefiles, I want to loop through them.

My individual commands are:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/ srs_def x.shp

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:27700 x.geojson x.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

Make either a batch script to run in the main OSGeo4w shell, or a shell script to run in the MSYS shell. To get an idea of what these look like, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7806/1872

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to batch gdal or ogr command is to use python (you can use it directly in OSGeo4w by launching python):

```
import os
os.system('ogr2ogr -s_srs http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/ srs_def x.shp')
os.system('ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:27700 x.geojson x.shp')
```

Then, you can then just make a simple loop.